# Error with Relational Table in Doctrine

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to follow the example from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616157/doctrine-2-and-many-to-many-link-table-with-an-extra-field) to do a many to many relationship with an extra field with Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework 1. My code looks like this:

**User Entity**

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UserChannel", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $userChannel;

    /**
     * Entity constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userChannel = new ArrayCollection(); 
    }

   --GETTERS AND SETTERS--

}
```

**Channel Entity**

```
class Channel
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $channel_id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Userchannel", mappedBy="channel")
     */
    private $userChannel;


    /**
     * Entity constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userChannel = new ArrayCollection();     
    }

    --GETTERS AND SETTERS--
}
```

**Relational UserChannel Entity:**

```
class UserChannel
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(name="channel_id", type="integer", length=11)
     *  @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Channel", inversedBy="userChannel")
     *  @JoinColumn(name="channel_id", referencedColumnName="channel_id")
     */
    private $channel;   

    /** @Column(name="user_id", type="integer", length=11)  
     *  @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userChannel")
     *  @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    private $user;

     /**
     * Entity constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    --GETTERS AND SETTERS--
}
```

Now, in my controller I have the following:

```
           $user = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->find(1);

        $userChannel = $user->getUserChannel();

        foreach($userChannel as $channel){
            print_r($channel->getChannel());
        }
```

I get two errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in /Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1396

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1401
**205**
```

But I still get the right channel id (the id in with the stars).

I have tried many things, but I still can't, by getting a User, get the Channel related to that User nor by getting the Channel, get the Users related to that channel. Am I using the relations correctly?  Would really appreciate the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made same mistake myself when I was starting off with Doctrine.

You cannot mix `Column` and `JoinColumn` annotations. Try removing `Column` annotation from `user` and `channel` properties within `UserChannel`...

Comment: Let me tell you: You rock!

Comment: If you use Doctrine's default naming scheme for foreign keys (i.e. property + '_id'), I'd prefer to delete the @JoinColumn annotation instead.