# Adding extra field in many_to_many symfony2 relationship

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, sonata-admin, symfony-2.5

Im looking for a way to handle many_to many relationship in symfony2 with extra field, I have 3 entities : Skill/Training/Skill-Training .Every training should affect some skills and increment the level of those skills.
So Skill-Training table is like this (skill_id,training_id,target_level)

In the Form of the Training i want to list all skills and the target level with each skill, so i can choose a skill and add the target level (integer from 1 to 5) that will be affected with this Training. I want to do this in the Add Form of the Training entity.

I use Sonata Admin Bundle To generate my Admin Classes ,i can render the list of skills with the checkbox easly (using type collection , and the option expanded true , multiple true ) but im wondering how to render the extra field target_level in front of each skill in the form of Training ??

I will be very greatful if you help me. Im looking for the solution for 3 days without any progress ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are the similar questions:

[Doctrine2: Best way to handle many-to-many with extra columns in reference table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table)

[Doctrine 2 and Many-to-many link table with an extra field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616157/doctrine-2-and-many-to-many-link-table-with-an-extra-field)

TL;DR: Unfortunately, relationships can't have any extra fields. You need to create one more entity, which would have two relations (with Skill and Training entities) and property for target level.

Comment: thanks kozlice ,  Now I get my relationship working perfectly