# Doctrine Join Many To Many without association

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

**I have:** two entities with undirectional M:M association.

```
class ShareInfo
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Item")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="share_info_items",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="share_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     *
     * @var Item[]
     */
    private $items;
}

class Item
{
    // ...

    // This entity has no association with ShareInfo,
    // because M:M is undirectional and defined in ShareInfo entity
}
```

**What I want:**
Select data from items table (Item entity), where at least one M:M record between Item and ShareInfo exists.

**My suggestion which doesn't work (I've got a semantic error)**:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('i')
    ->from(Item::class, 'i')
    ->innerJoin(ShareInfo::class, 'shareInfo', 'WITH', 'shareInfo.items = i');
```

In pure SQL I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
INNER JOIN share_info_items shareInfo
    ON shareInfo.item_id = i.id
```

Can't believe there is no DQL analog for this. The only solution I can imagine is to split undirectional M:M association into bi-directional

P.S. This question has no duplicates, I checked well.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @semsem I don't remember to be honest. But now I'd use a MtM relationship with an intermediate table. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616157/doctrine-2-and-many-to-many-link-table-with-an-extra-field/15630665#15630665
Looks like there is no solution for one-directional association.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I was dealing with the same problem and found a working solution. You need to add `ShareInfo::class` using alias, join the `ShareInfo::class` items using this alias and then filter the `Item::class` ids using `where()`:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('i')
    ->from(Item::class, 'i')
    ->from(ShareInfo::class, 'shareInfo')
    ->innerJoin('shareInfo.items', 'items')
    ->where('items.id = i.id');
```

Answer (score -1):

The way to achieve this is through a subquery:

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$queryBuilder1=$em->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder1->select(array('DISTINCT i.id'))
          ->from('AppBundle:ShareInfo', 'share_info')
          ->innerJoin('share_info.items', 'i');
$queryBuilder=$em->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('i')
         ->from('AppBundle:items', 'i')
         ->where($queryBuilder->expr()
         ->in('i.id',$queryBuilder1->getDql()));
```