# How to add additional columns to a join table in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to create a notification system. There is a `Notification` class. A notification can be assigned to more than one users, not just one.

There is a joint table `user_notifications`, with two columns: `user_id` and `notification_id`

The definition of the `$notifications` in the user class is this:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Notification")
 * @JoinTable(name="user_notifications",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="notification_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *      )
 **/
private $notifications;
```

Everything works fine. But I would like to add a new column to the `user_notifications` table, where I would like to store, if the notification is read by the given user, or not. How should I manage it in Doctrine2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to refactor your entities to introduce a new and transform your `user_notifications` adjacency table into an entity.

**Solution**

Transform you table as follows: [image]

Then refactor your associations as follows:

***User entity***

```
...
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UserNotification", mappedBy="notification_id")
 **/
private $notifications;
```

***Notification entity***

```
...
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UserNotification", mappedBy="user_id")
 **/
private $users;
```

***UserNotification entity***

```
/** @Entity **/
class UserNotification {
...
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="notifications")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $user_id;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Notification", inversedBy="users")
 * @JoinColumn(name="notification_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $notification_id;

/** @Column(type="boolean") */
private $read;
```

Comment: Simple and Precise - thanks, tipping my hat :)

Comment: I think your mapping is wrong according to this article: https://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/06/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns/#:~:text=When%20extra%20columns%20are%20introduced,give%20it%20an%20appropriate%20name.

So in User Entity you should map like this:
@OneToMany(targetEntity="UserNotification", mappedBy="user_id")

And in Notification like this:
@OneToMany(targetEntity="UserNotification", mappedBy="notification_id")

Otherwise if you call the relation getters in each entity, it will return you the users when you call getNotifications

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create new entity with this extra column.

You can find details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15630665/1348344