# How to implement many-to-many with extra fields in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have "customers", "products" and "versions" tables.Each customer, can have more than one product, and each product has more than one version. I have created many-to-many relation "customers_products" and everything works perfect.

Also I have created one-to-many relation between "products" and "versions".

QUESTION:
How to add an extra column (version_id) in "customers_products" table so I can build form where user can choose products and version to create new customer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once an association has data, it's no more an association.

You have to implement two `ManyToOne` instead of a `ManyToMany`.

See this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15630665/4363634) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616157/doctrine-2-and-many-to-many-link-table-with-an-extra-field) for a full example.

You can get a lot of other examples by googling the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extra column to the association of a many-to-many it actually changes the meaning of that relationship. In order to represent that with Doctrine, you'd need to change the association to be a one-to-many/many-to-one between the three entities.

You'll end up with three entities in your domain model, which would allow you to access to the version of a CustomerProduct entity.

You can read a bit more detailed explanation in [Doctrine's docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: The link is now pointing to the current location