# Laravel doctrine2 many to many relation with extra column

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, entity-relationship

So I'm beginning to struggle with Doctrine2 when it comes to a many-to-many relation for a project where the relation has 1 extra column.

I have the following tables:

- Profiles

  - id
  - extra data
- Skills

  - id
  - name
- profile_has_skills

  - profile_id
  - skill_id
  - level

Now I added the level column later on, and noticed some problems happening, of course I am missing level now whenever I try to create the relation.
My question is, with the code below, how would I go over to add this in my doctrine?

My controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $time = new DateTime();

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'profile_skills' => 'required'
    ]);

    $this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

    try {
        $profile = new Profile(
            $request->input('company_id'),
            $request->input('name'),
            $request->input('lastname'),
            $request->input('gender'),
            new DateTime(),
            $time,
            $time
        );

        $company = $this->em->getRepository(Company::class)->find($request->input('company_id'));
        $profile->addCompany($company);

        foreach($request->input('profile_skills') as $skill => $level) {
            $skill = $this->em->getRepository(Skill::class)->find($skill);
            $skill->level = $level;
            $profile->addSkill($skill);
        }

        $this->em->persist($profile);
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->getConnection()->commit();

    } catch (OptimisticLockException $e) {

        $this->em->getConnection()->rollBack();

        throw $e;
    }

    return redirect(route('profiles.index'));
}
```

My ProfileHasSkill entity looks as follow:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="profile_has_skill")
 *
 */
class ProfileHasSkill
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="integer", name="profile_id")
 */
protected $profile_id;


/**
 * @Column(type="integer", name="skill_id")
 */
protected $skill_id;

/**
 * @Column(type="integer", name="level")
 */
protected $level;

/**
 * @param $profile_id
 * @param $skill_id
 * @param $level
 */
public function __construct($profile_id, $skill_id, $level = 0)
{
    $this->profile_id = $profile_id;
    $this->skill_id = $skill_id;
    $this->level = $level;
}
```

And my addSkill method inside the profile entity is as follow:

```
public function addSkill(Skill $skill)
{
    if ($this->skills->contains($skill)) {
        return;
    }
    return $this->skills->add($skill);
}
```

But anytime I try to run this it gives me the following error

```
An exception occurred while executing 
'INSERT INTO profile_has_skill (profile_id, skill_id) VALUES (?, ?)' 
with params [3, 2]: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'level' 
doesn't have a default value
```

Now I know one way to get rid of this error is setting a default value in the database, but I much rather just find out why it's not picking up my skill level that I'm also passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my solution which has worked, by reading another question passed by [@Nicola Havric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9332897/nikola-gavric) - [Read as follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616157/doctrine-2-and-many-to-many-link-table-with-an-extra-field) That doctrine does not support extra columns in a many-to-many relation. Thus you should use the relation as it's own entity. My own solution was to change the way I wanted it to run with flushing.

In my controller I changed my code as follow:

```
try {
    $profile = new Profile(
        $request->input('company_id'),
        $request->input('name'),
        $request->input('lastname'),
        $request->input('gender'),
        new DateTime(),
        $time,
        $time
    );

    $company = $this->em->getRepository(Company::class)->find($request->input('company_id'));
    $profile->addCompany($company);
    //Flush the user, so I can grab it's profile ID
    $this->em->persist($profile);
    $this->em->flush();

    foreach($request->input('profile_skills') as $skill => $level) {
        $skill = $this->em->getRepository(Skill::class)->find($skill);
        $skill->level = $level;
        $profile->addSkill($skill);
    }


    $this->em->getConnection()->commit();
```

Inside my Profile Entity function:

```
public function addSkill(Skill $skill)
{
    //I left this check since it only checks if the relation is set already. If so, it will skip it.
    if ($this->skills->contains($skill)) {
        return;
    }

    //Since this function gets called inside a loop, I can call the entity to add a new "relation" to the table.
    (new ProfileHasSkill($this->getId(), $skill, $skill->level))->addSkill($this->getId(), $skill, $skill->level);

    return true;
}
```

Inside my ProfileHasSkill entity:

```
 public function addSkill($profileId, $skill)
{
    //Creating a new ProfileHasSkill inside the table.
    $profileSkill = new ProfileHasSkill(
        $profileId,
        $skill->getId(),
        $skill->level
    );

    /*Since I do a roll-back inside my controller in case something goes wrong.
       I decided to add the flush here. 
       As far no additional checks where needed in my case 
       since I require a Profile instance and a Skill instance inside the Profile entity.*/
    EntityManager::persist($profileSkill);
    EntityManager::flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with many-to-many relationships is that any additional columns other than two primary keys from both tables are considered **pivot** columns, when attaching entities to such relationships you want to use the method **attach** which accepts array of ids as first parameter and an array with **pivot** columns, take the following into consideration.

```
public function addSkill(Skill $skill)
{
    if ($this->skills->contains($skill)) {
        return;
    }
    //Dunno what this method does
    return $this->skills->add($skill);
    //But this is the correct way of adding a skill
    $this->skills->attach($skill->id, ['level' => $skill->level]);
}
```

Hope this can clarify few things even though Eloquent was used as an example; [here is the manual link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) for the above code.

Comment: I tried this, but sadly doctrine2 does not has the attach method, problem being doctrine2 was a requirement duo to faster speed on big databases and thus I cannot use Eloquent :( , also the add method is a doctrine method which will automatically fill the profile_has_skills table, but it's missing the "level" parameter, which is odd since I am adding the level inside the controller, or at least I thought so

Comment: I just stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616157/doctrine-2-and-many-to-many-link-table-with-an-extra-field which means that your profile_has_skills entity won't be able to have additional fields, which in this case is level, am I wrong?

Comment: Ah what a bummer! though, I guess I have to add my own functions to doctrine to achieve this.

Comment: True, I think it's a big minus towards Doctrine, but, good luck :D

Comment: I found a working solution, in case of intrest you can read it above.