# Allowing Symfony 4 and Doctrine for duplicate ManyToMany relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, symfony4

I want to create ManyToMany relation with duplicate options. One USER can have many CARS and many CARS can belong to various USERs. At the same time, one USER can own many cars of the same type.

How do I solve this in Symfony 4 and Doctrine?

Comment: If by **car** you mean the car make, then please see my answer. If by **car** you mean the physical vehicle, then it's logical that you can't have the same car twice. In that case you should rethink your application design.

Comment: The answer by cezar gives the solution. In addition, kind suggestion, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616157/doctrine-2-and-many-to-many-link-table-with-an-extra-field   The question could be similar and the accepted answer explains the reasons to "break" the relation.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you have two entities, as described, `User` and `Car`, and define a `ManyToMany` relation between them. It could look like this:

**`User.php`**

```
class User
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Car", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $cars;
    // ...
}
```

**`Car.php`**

```
class Car
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="cars")
     */
    // ...
    private $users;
}
```

Doctrine will automatically create an intermediate table between them, something like `users_cars` with two columns: `user_id` and `car_id`. They will hold the foreign keys to `users` and `cars` respectively. Your problem is that Doctrine creates a composite primary key of these two columns, which means it must be unique and you can't have something like:

```
 user_id | car_id
------------------
   1     |   1
   1     |   1
```

which should be for example something like:

```
Konrad | Porsche 911
Konrad | Porsche 911
```

With other words, Konrad has two cars of the same model.

You could break the `ManyToMany` relation into two `ManyToOne` and define your own entity for the intermediate table:

**`Ownership.php`**

```
class Ownership
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="cars_owned")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Car", inversedBy="owners")
     */
    private $car;
    // ...
}
```

Set up the appropriate `OneToMany` relations in `User` and `Car`. Now you can have duplicates in your table `ownerships`. This gives you the flexibility to add more information about the ownership, maybe purchase date when the user has acquired the car.

I'd like to stress that naming is one of the most important things in programming. Name your classes and methods with some forethought. What to they describe, what do they do?

To me it wasn't immediately obvious how a user can own the same car more then once. I was thinking of a physical vehicle by the term car. Maybe you should rather call that entity `CarModel` or `CarBrand`. Also `User` isn't very intuitive, I'd rather choose `Owner` or `Person`, but this depends on the further business logic of your application.